# How to narrow a query parameter on Google Assistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I got the following feedback from Google team:

The query pattern for the initialTrigger you provided “$SchemaOrg_Place:geo-city” is intended for discovery and is too broad for you Action.

I am not sure what this means and how can I correct this so that my action is approved. I am using API.AI platform. My action captures a City Name as a request parameter. I have defined an entity parameter name is geo-city and Entity type is  @sys.geo-city. 
[image]

Following is  a screenshot from from API AI console 
[image]

Comment: You're using API.AI? Can you also include a screen shot of the "User Says" section of this Intent and if this is the Welcome intent?

Comment: Yes, I am using API AI. I added  screenshot of the "User Says" section. And, this is NOT a welcome intent.

Answer (score 1):

Initial triggers are used for discovery within the system. Assume you defined an initial trigger "find a groceries store in $SchemaOrg_Place:city" in your action "Grocery Finder", this may happen:

User: Ok Google, I need to find a groceries store in San Francisco
Assistant: Grocery Finder can help you with that, here is Grocery Finder:

In a way initial triggers can be looked at like SEO keywords. Just having "$SchemaOrg_Place:city" as an initial trigger would mean that any time somebody says a city name to Google Assistant your action may jump in which is likely not what the user was looking for and I guess this is what they mean with "too broad".

Comment: Thanks for posting. I'll try this and if it works, I'll accept your post as an answer.